# VSCode: No auto-suggestion while importing modules in node express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, babeljs

I am using babel, eslint, and prettier for Node Rest API. To use absolute path I am using a package called `babel-plugin-module-resolver` but when I do use ES6 imports, I noticed that there is no auto suggestions. However, when I use relative path, everything seems to work perfectly fine.

Relative Path (Desired behavior with ES6 import and Absolute path)
[image]

Absoulte Path (No suggestions)
[image]

Here are my configuration files

**1. package.json**

```
{
  "name": "prod-js-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Production level starter for node.js based express RESTFull APIs",
  "main": "src/server.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run clean && babel ./src --out-dir build --copy-files",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node build/server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/server.js",
    "clean": "rm -rf build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "module-alias": "^2.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.6",
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
    "@babel/node": "^7.16.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.13.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2"
  }
}
```

**2. eslint.json**

```
{
  "env": {
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": ["airbnb-base", "prettier"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest"
  },
  "rules": {
    // "func-names": "off",
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "no-unused-vars": "warn",
    "no-console": "warn"
  },
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "babel-module": {}
    }
  }
}
```

**3. .babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["."],
        "alias": {
          "@src": "./src"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Please help me to get those suggestions working like before. Its a simple feature but quite efficient.